# Groovy does not recognize kotlin constructor in spock

Tags: kotlin, groovy, spock

I have application written in kotlin. Now I want to write some tests using spock and groovy. The problem I have, is that groovy does not recognize kotlin constructors with optional argument (?) and error occurs: "Constructor cannot be applied to"

I am using gradle to build project.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

group 'com.pl'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile(
            'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4',
            'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4',
    )
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: It would also help to add the kotlin and groovy code, that fail. Also there are way newer versions of Groovy and Spock out there - I doubt it will help though.

Comment: I agree. Welcome to SO. Please first learn about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question, transforming it into an MCVE. The Gradle build script is a good first step, but a minimal sample Kotlin application + a Spock test reproducing your problem are essential.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Kotlin constructors with optional arguments are generated as one constructor taking all arguments in Java code, so the optionality only applies in Kotlin code. However, there is an annotation, [`@JvmOverloads`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/) that you can apply to constructors and functions to make the Kotlin compiler emit multiple Java signatures, making the code optional also on Java's side.

Here is an example with Kotlin and Java (I don't know Groovy much but I'm sure it'll work similarly):

```
class Foo @JvmOverloads constructor(
    val bar : String = "test"
)
```

```java
public static void main(String args[])
{
     Foo foo = new Foo(); // bar is set to test
     System.out.println(foo.getBar()); // will print test
}
```